# login to page using selenium

Tags: selenium, authentication, selenium-chromedriver

Attached below is the login page screenshot. I am unable to figure out how to find `class` name of username or what can be the `id` for putting username. Basically i am trying to login here. [image]

I have tried

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Username')]").sendKeys("thakneh")
```

but the error i am getting is:
 `'list' object has no attribute 'sendKeys'`.
Also, `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Username')]")` part returns empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list' object has no attribute 'sendKeys
```

this is because, you are using `find_elements` which will return a list in `Selenium-Python` bindings.

you can not perform `send_keys` to a list in Selenium - Python. It has to be a single web element.

try `find_element` instead. (this will return a `web element` not list of `web elements`)

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Username')]").sendKeys("thakneh")
```

**Update 1  :**

```
driver.get("Your URL")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Username']/../following-sibling::input"))).send_keys('username')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Password']/../following-sibling::input"))).send_keys('password')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Sign In']/.."))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: if you can share page URL, we can probably give you more constructive answer.

Comment: this web app is developed by developement in my organization so it runs only on US servers. i changed the line in my code but it gave me error:

` NoSuchElementException:  Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(), 'Username')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.101)
`

Comment: okay can you do this :- `print(driver.page_source)` and share the HTML code, so that I can give you a better solution

Comment: It gives below output:
`<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"message":"Not Found"}</pre></body></html>`

Comment: no it can not be this small, are you sure ?

Comment: yes sorry it has bigger response . how may i send you. should i edit in question itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234803/discussion-between-nehat280-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: you can, but I would suggest you to write everything in a text file and upload to some hosting website (free of cost) and then share the link here.

Comment: can you visit: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234803/discussion-between-nehat280-and-cruisepandey
i have uploaded here for convenience

Comment: @nehat280 : Can you check out the updated 1 code above, I hope that will help you.